# Calculate Median of a column (Days on Shelf) for different ranges of another column (Price)

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find the Median number of Carats of Gold for each day of the year. And I need to segregate these as per the price range of Gold in different columns.

The data:

```
Create table Daily_Gold_Rate
( S_No int, Dt datetime, Carat int, Gold_Rate numeric(18,2))

Insert into Daily_Gold_Rate values(1,'2013-01-03',18,155.00)
Insert into Daily_Gold_Rate values(2,'2013-01-03',22,190.50)
Insert into Daily_Gold_Rate values(3,'2013-01-03',24,202.23)
Insert into Daily_Gold_Rate values(4,'2013-01-03',18,400.00)
Insert into Daily_Gold_Rate values(5,'2013-01-03',22,480.50)
Insert into Daily_Gold_Rate values(6,'2013-01-03',24,671.23)

Insert into Daily_Gold_Rate values(7,'2013-01-04',18,153.00)
Insert into Daily_Gold_Rate values(8,'2013-01-04',22,191.00)
Insert into Daily_Gold_Rate values(9,'2013-01-04',24,202.25)
Insert into Daily_Gold_Rate values(10,'2013-01-04',18,351.00)
Insert into Daily_Gold_Rate values(11,'2013-01-04',22,892.00)
Insert into Daily_Gold_Rate values(12,'2013-01-04',24,1003.25)

Insert into Daily_Gold_Rate values(13,'2013-01-05',18,150.00)
Insert into Daily_Gold_Rate values(14,'2013-01-05',22,190.00)
Insert into Daily_Gold_Rate values(15,'2013-01-05',24,203.25)
Insert into Daily_Gold_Rate values(16,'2013-01-05',18,773.00)
Insert into Daily_Gold_Rate values(17,'2013-01-05',22,542.00)
Insert into Daily_Gold_Rate values(18,'2013-01-05',24,182.25)

Insert into Daily_Gold_Rate values(19,'2013-01-06',18,158.00)
Insert into Daily_Gold_Rate values(20,'2013-01-06',22,189.50)
Insert into Daily_Gold_Rate values(21,'2013-01-06',24,201.50)
Insert into Daily_Gold_Rate values(22,'2013-01-06',18,624.00)
Insert into Daily_Gold_Rate values(23,'2013-01-06',
Insert into Daily_Gold_Rate values(24,'2013-01-06',24,411.50)
```

Simple PERCENTILE_CONT shown below:

```
Select Dt, Carat, Gold_Rate, PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 
Carat) OVER (PARTITION BY Carat) AS MedianCont
from Daily_Gold_Rate
order by Dt;Expected output is like this:
```

Returns this Data:

```
Dt            | Carat | Gold_Rate | MedianCont
2013-01-03 00:00:00.000 | 18 | 155.00 | 18
2013-01-03 00:00:00.000 | 18 | 400.00 | 18
2013-01-03 00:00:00.000 | 22 | 480.50 | 22
2013-01-03 00:00:00.000 | 22 | 190.50 | 22
2013-01-03 00:00:00.000 | 24 | 202.23 | 24
2013-01-03 00:00:00.000 | 24 | 671.23 | 24
2013-01-04 00:00:00.000 | 24 | 202.25 | 24
2013-01-04 00:00:00.000 | 24 | 1003.25 | 24
2013-01-04 00:00:00.000 | 18 | 153.00 | 18
2013-01-04 00:00:00.000 | 18 | 351.00 | 18
2013-01-04 00:00:00.000 | 22 | 892.00 | 22
2013-01-04 00:00:00.000 | 22 | 191.00 | 22
2013-01-05 00:00:00.000 | 22 | 542.00 | 22
2013-01-05 00:00:00.000 | 22 | 190.00 | 22
2013-01-05 00:00:00.000 | 18 | 150.00 | 18
2013-01-05 00:00:00.000 | 18 | 773.00 | 18
2013-01-05 00:00:00.000 | 24 | 203.25 | 24
2013-01-05 00:00:00.000 | 24 | 182.25 | 24
2013-01-06 00:00:00.000 | 24 | 201.50 | 24
2013-01-06 00:00:00.000 | 24 | 411.50 | 24
2013-01-06 00:00:00.000 | 18 | 158.00 | 18
2013-01-06 00:00:00.000 | 18 | 624.00 | 18
2013-01-06 00:00:00.000 | 22 | 735.50 | 22
2013-01-06 00:00:00.000 | 22 | 189.50 | 22
```

I need to pivot on Gold Price Range. So, I am trying through this query:

```
with a as (
    select year(Dt) as "year", month(Dt) as "month", day(Dt) as "day",
    case when Gold_Rate / 200 < 5 then Gold_Rate / 200 else 5 end as 
price_bucket,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(.50) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Carat) over (PARTITION BY 
day(Dt), month(Dt)) as MED_days
from Daily_Gold_Rate
group by year(Dt), month(Dt), day(Dt), Gold_Rate / 200, Carat)
select "year", "month", "day",
[1] as "less than 400", [2] as "400-599", [3] as "600-799", [4] as "800-
999", [5] as "Over 1000"
from a pivot (max(MED_days) for price_bucket in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])) p
order by "year", "month", "day";
```

But, this is what I am getting, instead. :(

```
Year | Month | Day | 1-399 | 400-599 | 600-799| 800-999| Over 1000
2013 | 1     | 3   | NULL  | 22      | NULL   | NULL   | NULL
2013 | 1     | 4   | NULL  | NULL    | NULL   | NULL   | 22
2013 | 1     | 5   | NULL  | NULL    | NULL   | NULL   | NULL
2013 | 1     | 6   | NULL  | NULL    | NULL   | NULL   | NULL
```

Comment: **MCVE** I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks, @Used_By_Already. From your suggestion, I believe that while describing my problem, I am missing the data creation part (insert, create). I have changed my description for better understanding. I hope this is alright, now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivoting before the percentile calculation:

> ```
> select distinct
>       dt
>     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ratelt400)      OVER (PARTITION BY dt) ratelt400
>     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ratebtwn400599) OVER (PARTITION BY dt) ratebtwn400599
>     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ratebtwn600799) OVER (PARTITION BY dt) ratebtwn600799
>     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ratebtwn800999) OVER (PARTITION BY dt) ratebtwn800999
>     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rateovr1000)    OVER (PARTITION BY dt) rateovr1000
>     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY caratlt400)      OVER (PARTITION BY dt) caratlt400
>     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY caratbtwn400599) OVER (PARTITION BY dt) caratbtwn400599
>     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY caratbtwn600799) OVER (PARTITION BY dt) caratbtwn600799
>     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY caratbtwn800999) OVER (PARTITION BY dt) caratbtwn800999
>     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY caratovr1000)    OVER (PARTITION BY dt) caratovr1000
> from (
> SELECT
>       DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, dt), 0) dt
>     , CASE WHEN Gold_Rate < 400               THEN Gold_Rate END ratelt400
>     , CASE WHEN Gold_Rate BETWEEN 400 AND 599 THEN Gold_Rate END ratebtwn400599
>     , CASE WHEN Gold_Rate BETWEEN 600 AND 799 THEN Gold_Rate END ratebtwn600799
>     , CASE WHEN Gold_Rate BETWEEN 800 AND 999 THEN Gold_Rate END ratebtwn800999
>     , CASE WHEN Gold_Rate >= 1000             THEN Gold_Rate END rateovr1000
>     , CASE WHEN Gold_Rate < 400               THEN carat END caratlt400
>     , CASE WHEN Gold_Rate BETWEEN 400 AND 599 THEN carat END caratbtwn400599
>     , CASE WHEN Gold_Rate BETWEEN 600 AND 799 THEN carat END caratbtwn600799
>     , CASE WHEN Gold_Rate BETWEEN 800 AND 999 THEN carat END caratbtwn800999
>     , CASE WHEN Gold_Rate >= 1000             THEN carat END caratovr1000
> FROM Daily_Gold_Rate
> ) d
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> dt                  | ratelt400 | ratebtwn400599 | ratebtwn600799 | ratebtwn800999 | rateovr1000 | caratlt400 | caratbtwn400599 | caratbtwn600799 | caratbtwn800999 | caratovr1000
> :------------------ | --------: | -------------: | -------------: | -------------: | ----------: | ---------: | --------------: | --------------: | --------------: | -----------:
> 03/01/2013 00:00:00 |     190.5 |         440.25 |         671.23 |           null |        null |         22 |              20 |              24 |            null |         null
> 04/01/2013 00:00:00 |   196.625 |           null |           null |            892 |     1003.25 |         20 |            null |            null |              22 |           24
> 05/01/2013 00:00:00 |   186.125 |            542 |            773 |           null |        null |         23 |              22 |              18 |            null |         null
> 06/01/2013 00:00:00 |     189.5 |          411.5 |            624 |           null |        null |         22 |              24 |              18 |            null |         null
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d193e85d65f5b5aa21e7f67a4b5095de)*

Below are some working queries for values by either carats or rates:

## revised answer:

**Rates by Day**

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT
>       DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, dt), 0) dt
>     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CASE WHEN Gold_Rate < 400               THEN Gold_Rate END) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, dt), 0)) lt400
>     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CASE WHEN Gold_Rate BETWEEN 400 AND 599 THEN Gold_Rate END) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, dt), 0)) btwn400599
>     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CASE WHEN Gold_Rate BETWEEN 600 AND 799 THEN Gold_Rate END) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, dt), 0)) btwn600799
>     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CASE WHEN Gold_Rate BETWEEN 800 AND 999 THEN Gold_Rate END) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, dt), 0)) btwn800999
>     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CASE WHEN Gold_Rate >= 1000             THEN Gold_Rate END) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, dt), 0)) ovr1000
> FROM Daily_Gold_Rate
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> dt                  |   lt400 | btwn400599 | btwn600799 | btwn800999 | ovr1000
> :------------------ | ------: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ------:
> 03/01/2013 00:00:00 |   190.5 |     440.25 |     671.23 |       null |    null
> 04/01/2013 00:00:00 | 196.625 |       null |       null |        892 | 1003.25
> 05/01/2013 00:00:00 | 186.125 |        542 |        773 |       null |    null
> 06/01/2013 00:00:00 |   189.5 |      411.5 |        624 |       null |    null
> ```

**Carats by Day**

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT
>       DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, dt), 0) dt
>     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CASE WHEN Gold_Rate < 400               THEN carat END) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, dt), 0)) lt400
>     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CASE WHEN Gold_Rate BETWEEN 400 AND 599 THEN carat END) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, dt), 0)) btwn400599
>     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CASE WHEN Gold_Rate BETWEEN 600 AND 799 THEN carat END) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, dt), 0)) btwn600799
>     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CASE WHEN Gold_Rate BETWEEN 800 AND 999 THEN carat END) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, dt), 0)) btwn800999
>     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CASE WHEN Gold_Rate >= 1000             THEN carat END) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, dt), 0)) ovr1000
> FROM Daily_Gold_Rate
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> dt                  | lt400 | btwn400599 | btwn600799 | btwn800999 | ovr1000
> :------------------ | ----: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ------:
> 03/01/2013 00:00:00 |    22 |         20 |         24 |       null |    null
> 04/01/2013 00:00:00 |    20 |       null |       null |         22 |      24
> 05/01/2013 00:00:00 |    23 |         22 |         18 |       null |    null
> 06/01/2013 00:00:00 |    22 |         24 |         18 |       null |    null
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4a59f9e5070448ee62345e0bd8f91c8d)*

**By Month:** FYI only

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT
>       DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, dt), 0) dt
>     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CASE WHEN Gold_Rate < 400               THEN Gold_Rate END) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, dt), 0)) lt400
>     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CASE WHEN Gold_Rate BETWEEN 400 AND 599 THEN Gold_Rate END) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, dt), 0)) btwn400599
>     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CASE WHEN Gold_Rate BETWEEN 600 AND 799 THEN Gold_Rate END) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, dt), 0)) btwn600799
>     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CASE WHEN Gold_Rate BETWEEN 800 AND 999 THEN Gold_Rate END) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, dt), 0)) btwn800999
>     , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CASE WHEN Gold_Rate >= 1000             THEN Gold_Rate END) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, dt), 0)) ovr1000
> FROM Daily_Gold_Rate
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> dt                  |  lt400 | btwn400599 | btwn600799 | btwn800999 | ovr1000
> :------------------ | -----: | ---------: | ---------: | ---------: | ------:
> 01/01/2013 00:00:00 | 190.25 |        446 |     671.23 |        892 | 1003.25
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e089ae8fad28f464fcc3d9697bf755ed)*

Comment: This is returning median of the whole price range (0-Max. Price) for the full time range. Employing (PARTITION BY month(datetime)) in the percentile_cont function partitioned the Median on monthly basis but it is still for the Whole price range for each month. How to get Median for separate price ranges?

Comment: Do the pivot of raw data into the columns first. Then run the window functions on the separate columns

Comment: Have now had a chance to work with the sample data and believe I have a working query for you.

Comment: Thanks, @Used_By_Already. I was making a basic error in case syntax. Need to percentile function and then the range under ORDER BY clause.

Comment: I don't know what you meant in the comment above this, but it does not make a difference to outcome if you pivot first, then calculate the percentile. I have added one more variant (at the top) which pivots first. Given that you haven't supplied an expected result I will leave this as it is.